# How can I get correct remaining Hours from two times in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to calculate the time remaining hours based on the difference of two times passing parameter in my function. I am passing  NetHrs , time2 as an argument in a javascript function but getting wrong remaining hours after calculation

1. I am passing NetHrs 7.30(intime), WorkHrs(outtime) as 3.22 Then the result should be given as 4.08. But it gives 4.80
2. If I am passing NetHrs 7.30 WorkHrs as 3.10 Then the result should be 4.20. This gives correct result
   But in first case my function gives wrong result. Please help
   Here is my function

```js
function GetNetHrs(inTime, outTime) {
    inTime = inTime.replace('.', ':');
    outTime = outTime.replace('.', ':');
   
    var indate = new Date("01/01/2018 " + inTime + ":00");
    var outdate = new Date("01/01/2018 " + outTime + ":00");    
    var diff = indate.getTime() - outdate.getTime();
    
    var msec = diff;
    var hh = Math.floor(msec / 1000 / 60 / 60);

    console.log(msec / 1000 / 60 / 60);
    msec -= hh * 1000 * 60 * 60;
    
    var mm = Math.floor(msec / 1000 / 60);
    msec -= mm * 1000 * 60;
    var ss = Math.floor(msec / 1000);
    msec -= ss * 1000;
    var netHrsStr = hh + "." + mm;
    return parseFloat(netHrsStr);
}

console.log(GetNetHrs("7.30","3.22"))
console.log(GetNetHrs("7.30","3.10"))
```

Comment: Try adding a `mm.padStart(2, "0");`. This will essentially 'pad' the beginning, so if the minutes are single digit, it will add a 0.

Comment: When I add mm.padStart(2, "0") it shows site.js:1404 Uncaught TypeError: mm.padStart is not a function

Comment: Oh, sorry! You have to convert it to a string first using `.toString()`.

Comment: Many Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure your `mm` value is `0n` not `n` - you can use `padStart` for that., but you must first turn it back to a string.

```js
function GetNetHrs(inTime, outTime) {
    inTime = inTime.replace('.', ':');
    outTime = outTime.replace('.', ':');
   
    var indate = new Date("01/01/2018 " + inTime + ":00");
    var outdate = new Date("01/01/2018 " + outTime + ":00");    
    var diff = indate.getTime() - outdate.getTime();
    
    var msec = diff;
    var hh = Math.floor(msec / 1000 / 60 / 60);

    console.log(msec / 1000 / 60 / 60);
    msec -= hh * 1000 * 60 * 60;
    
    var mm = Math.floor(msec / 1000 / 60);
    msec -= mm * 1000 * 60;
    var ss = Math.floor(msec / 1000);
    msec -= ss * 1000;
    var netHrsStr = hh + "." + mm.toString().padStart(2,"0");
    return parseFloat(netHrsStr);
}

console.log(GetNetHrs("7.30","3.22"))
console.log(GetNetHrs("7.30","3.10"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's wrong with your function but here's how I do it:

```
function diff_hours(dt2, dt1) 
 {

  var diff =(dt2.getTime() - dt1.getTime()) / 1000;
  diff /= (60 * 60);
  return Math.abs(Math.round(diff));
  
 }
```

this function Write will get time differences in hours between two dates.

now if you want to test it here's an example:

```
dt1 = new Date(2014,10,2);
dt2 = new Date(2014,10,3);
console.log(diff_hours(dt1, dt2));


dt1 = new Date("October 13, 2014 08:11:00");
dt2 = new Date("October 13, 2014 11:13:00");
console.log(diff_hours(dt1, dt2));
```

output:

```
24
3
```

If you want to learn more about it [ClickMe](https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-date-exercise-45.php)